# AJAX-handling form with switch slider inside

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm veeery new to all this jquery and ajax stuff, doing it like for the first time, and I need to build a crud operation interface. The biggest problem is that I have to use one bootstrap modal window for create and update user.

In this form I have two inputs for first and last names, and also slider for user status which should be 1 or 0 in the database.

For update it works for me in some way, but for adding I always have problem with this status field. The idea was to do if else block for this status property in ajax, but it keeps sending me an empty field.

**Modal window**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="userformModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">User Form</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <form action="" method="POST" id="user_form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Last name</label>
                     <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Status </label>
                    <label class="switch" style="margin-left: 20px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status"/>
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_status" id="hidden_status">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Form handling with ajax**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#user_form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "process.php",
                data : $("#user_form").serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response) {
                    // alert('ok2');
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.status) {
                        toastr.success(response.message);
                        $("#firstname").val(response.data.firstname);
                        $("#lastname").val(response.data.lastname);
                        $('#status').change(function () {
                            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                                $('#hidden_status').val(1);
                            } else {
                                $('#hidden_status').val(0);
                            }
                        });
                        $("#user_form")[0].reset();
                        $("#userformModal").modal('hide');
                        get_all_users();
                    }else{
                        toastr.error(response.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

**EDIT function**

```
function edit_record(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "process.php?edit_id="+id,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status) {
                $("#firstname").val(response.data.firstname);
                $("#user_id").val(response.data.id);
                $("#lastname").val(response.data.lastname);
                $('#status').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                        $('#hidden_status').val(1);
                    } else {
                        $('#hidden_status').val(0);
                    }
                });
                $("#userformModal").modal('show');
              //  setTimeout(function(){ alert(response.message);window.location.reload(); }, 3000);

            }else{
               alert(response.message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit button**

```
   <td class="text-center align-middle"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary badge" onclick="edit_record(<?= $row['id']; ?>)" >Edit</button>
```

**Php**

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $name = $_POST['firstname']. ' '.$_POST['lastname'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $status = $_POST['hidden_status'];


    if ($user_id == '') {
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(name, role, status) VALUES ('$name','$role','$status')");
        $message = "Record created successfully.";
    } else {
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `user` SET `name`='$name',`role`='$role', `status` = '$status' WHERE `id`='$user_id'");
        $message = "Record updated successfully.";
    }
    $result = $statement->execute();

    if ($result) {
        $response = array('status' => true, 'message' => $message);
    }else{
        $response = array('status' => false, 'message' => 'Error');
    }

    echo json_encode($response);exit();
}
```

How I can make it work with ajax?

Comment: try in js file: response = JSON.parse(response) then response.status

Comment: You have a checkbox named `status` (the value of which you don't seem to access on the server side at all), and a hidden field named `hidden_status` - which you do access, but it is unclear where that one is supposed to get any value set in the first place. You add a change handler for the checkbox that will set the value - but you only do that in your AJAX success callback, so on the _first_ request, this won't have any other value than an empty string.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your advice! I tried to do it with defining some vars in the beginning of ajax call, but it wasn't successful. Maybe I did it the wrong way. Could you please tell me how to set the value on the first request properly as well?

Comment: Just put the `#status` change handler _outside_ of the AJAX callback, before you even make the AJAX call ...?

Comment: @Turendu Thanks for your reply, I'll check this too

Comment: @CBroe No success. I also tried to move it before AJAX call while saving the                         $('#status').val(response.data.status) line inside if block of success call function - same result as before

Comment: This should be completely outside of your submit handler - so that the event handler is registered for the element, before you even start submitting this. Then the field should be filled with the correct value already, at the time you handle the submit, and `$("#user_form").serialize()` should "catch" it together with the rest of the form field data.

Comment: Although not really clear what this hidden field should be good for in the first place; you might as well just check whether you got a parameter for the checkbox in the submitted data, or not. (Checkboxes only cause an entry in the form submission data set, if they were checked.)

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, before submit I tried as well. I'm doing it like this cause it worked out for me in edit function. And I'm sharing the same modal and one block of php for update and insert. I've added this edit function and it's button in my post. There this hidden_status thing works, so I was just figuring out how to make it work with submit the same way

Comment: @CBroe In the end of the day moving it right before submit worked out. Thank you so much!